# If-Else control structure problem

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

Why does below control structure return 250 in both value scenarios?

```
function bonusCalculate(uint _value) public pure returns(uint) {

        if(_value <= 50 ether) {
          return 250;
        } else if (_value >= 100 ether) {
          return 500; 
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because your code is equivalent to

```
function bonusCalculate(uint _value) public pure returns(uint) {

        if(_value <= 50*1000000000000000000) {
          return 250;
        } else if (_value >= 100*1000000000000000000) {
          return 500; 
        }
     }
```

1 ether= 1000000000000000000.

Comment: Legendary Badr, forgot about that